# Automatic Deletion of Duplicate SQL Records based on date or count

Tags: sql, visual-studio-lightswitch

After importing Excel data from a LightSwitch application into a holding table in SQL Server I end up with duplicate records.  I need a way to remove the duplicates that can either be executed from LightSwitch or something that will automatically run in SQL after/during insert.  I thought about a trigger, but I'm not sure it's the best solution.
The duplicates will be something like this

```
DocName|DocUser|DocType|DocDate|
test    user1   word    10/12/2012
test    user1   word    10/12/2012
test2   user2   word    10/11/2012
test2   user2   word    10/12/2012
```

In the case of the first set of duplicates either record can be deleted so I have one record.
However in the second case the record with the date of 10/11/2012 would need to be deleted.
I'm not apposed to a Stored Procedure if it can be executed by from LightSwitch.  I know it can be done with a series of queries but I'm not sure how that could be executed from LightSwitch?

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with Lightswitch so apologies if any of this is not relevant, but speaking from the SQL side a stored procedure you could use to delete the duplicates is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DeleteDuplicatesFromT
AS
BEGIN
    WITH CTE AS 
    (   SELECT  DocName, 
                DocUser, 
                DocType, 
                DocDate, 
                [RowNumber] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocName, DocUser, DocType ORDER BY DocDate DESC)
        FROM    T
    )
    DELETE  CTE
    WHERE   RowNumber > 1;
END
```

[Example on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0d62/2)

**HOWEVER**

I'd advise managing this before/during the insert stage, you can either do this in the application code, and ensure only unique records are passed to the table to begin with, or use a procedure again to perform the insert. To do the latter you will first need to create a `TYPE` to handle your new records:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TableTypeParameter AS TABLE
(   DocName VARCHAR(5), 
    DocUser VARCHAR(5), 
    DocType VARCHAR(4), 
    DocDate DATETIME
);
```

You can fill this in your client code (using System.Data.DataTable) and pass this as a parameter to your stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.BulkInsert @NewRecords dbo.TableTypeParameter READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    WITH NewRecords AS
    (   SELECT  DocName, DocType, DocUser, DocDate = MAX(DocDate)
        FROM    @NewRecords
        GROUP BY DocName, DocType, DocUser
    )
    MERGE INTO T 
    USING NewRecords nr 
        ON T.DocName = nr.DocName
        AND T.DocType = nr.DocType
        AND T.DocUser = nr.DocUser
    WHEN MATCHED AND nr.DocDate > T.DocDate THEN UPDATE
        SET DocDate = nr.DocDate
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (DocName, DocUser, DocType, DocDate)
        VALUES (nr.DocName, nr.DocUser, nr.DocType, nr.DocDate);

END;
```

**EDIT**

The procedure to insert can fairly easily be turned into a trigger if this is what is required:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.T_InsteadOfInsert 
    ON T
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    WITH NewRecords AS
    (   SELECT  DocName, DocType, DocUser, DocDate = MAX(DocDate)
        FROM    inserted
        GROUP BY DocName, DocType, DocUser
    )
    MERGE INTO T 
    USING NewRecords nr 
        ON T.DocName = nr.DocName
        AND T.DocType = nr.DocType
        AND T.DocUser = nr.DocUser
    WHEN MATCHED AND nr.DocDate > T.DocDate THEN UPDATE
        SET DocDate = nr.DocDate
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (DocName, DocUser, DocType, DocDate)
        VALUES (nr.DocName, nr.DocUser, nr.DocType, nr.DocDate);

END
```

Comment: Will that handle deletion of both instances that I mentioned?  Both when all fields are the same and when only the date differs?

Comment: No, it would not have handled deletion in the instances you mentioned, I did not read the question properly. Sorry. I have updated the answer so that now in the case of duplicates only the record with the Newest doc date is kept, or in the case of the bulk insert, any existing records are updated with the new doc date where necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It turns out calling stored procedures from Lightswitch is difficult.  May end up having to put a trigger to call if the SP if possible.

Comment: @JoshLarsen I've added the query to use to create a trigger to handle the inserts.

Comment: Thanks I was able to modify some of that code to exactly what I wanted.  I would upvote but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @JoshLarsen You can still [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this will let others know the solution worked (It will also boost your reputation).

Answer (score 0):

A user on the MSDN forums had a similar problem using the Excel Importer. He wrote a few functions to check and validate his tables to prevent entry of and remove existing duplicates. Take a look: [Automatic Validation Error Handling](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/24381663-fd59-47cc-b13f-c4ab8d358e84).